# SQL: Pivoting on more than one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
Name |  Period |  Value1 |  Value2
-----+---------+---------+-------
 A       1        2        3
 A       2        5        4
 A       3        6        7
 B       1        2        3
 B       2        5        4
 B       3        6        7
```

I need results like

```
Name | Value1 |  Value2
-----+--------+------
 A   | 2,5,6  |  3,4,7
 B   | 2,5,6  |  3,4,7
```

Number of periods is dynamic but I know how to handle it so, for simplicity, let's say there are 3 periods

The query below gives me results for Value1. How can I get results for both?
I can always do them separately and then do a join but the table is really big and I need "combine"  four values, not two. Can I do it in one statement?

```
SELECT Name,
[1]+','+ [2] + ','+ [3]  ValueString
FROM   (
 select  Name,  period,   cpr from #MyTable     
 ) as s     
  PIVOT(SUM(Value1)        
   FOR period IN ([1],[2],[3])
```

Comment: Just note that this isn't really a pivot - it's an aggregation. A pivot is explicitly turning values in a column into a new column. In this case you could, for example, create columns for each period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.  Combining the values into strings is a bit tricky, requiring XML logic in SQL Server:

```
select n.name,
       stuff((select ',' + cast(value1 as varchar(max))
              from t
              where n.name = t.name
              order by t.period
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as values1,
       stuff((select ',' + cast(value2 as varchar(max))
              from t
              where n.name = t.name
              order by t.period
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as values2
from (select distinct name
      from t
     ) n;
```

Your values look like numbers, hence the explicit cast and the lack of concern for XML special characters.

You may ask why this does the `distinct` in a subquery rather than in the outer query.  If done in the outer query, then the SQL engine will probably do the aggregation for every row *before* doing the `distinct`.  I'm not sure if the optimizer is good enough run the subqueries only once per name.

Comment: might want to add order by period to the stuff queries.

Comment: @SqlZim . . . Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using Group By with stuff function and get expected result

```
SELECT Name ,  STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(Value1 AS VARCHAR) FROM #MyTable T2 WHERE T1.Name = T2.Name FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') Value1
        ,  STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(Value2 AS VARCHAR) FROM #MyTable T3 WHERE T1.Name = T3.Name FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') Value2 FROM #MyTable T1 GROUP BY Name
```